# Изменение вопроса после ответа

Tags: обсуждение

Обычно не жалуюсь, но вот сейчас задело. Вопрос [**Как подсчитать количество цифр в файле**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1507348/228791). В тексте вопроса то же самое - *Мне нужно подсчитать именно количество цифр*.

Отвечаю.

Получаю минус с комментарием

> мне эти цифры (только цифры) необходимо получить из файла в консоль что бы Я мог потом з ними работать к примеру: получения количества положительных и отрицательных цифр, количество парных и не парных, какая цифра самая большая а какая самая маленькая и перезаписи этих цифр в другой файл к примеру

Это же совершенно иная задача (не говоря о том, что надо пояснять, что это значит - "получить в консоль"). При этом сам вопрос так и не был изменен.

Так, утрируя, скоро будет вопрос "умножить 2 на 2", а в коммментарии - "мне надо написать программу решения тригонометрического уравнения, в котором один из параметров равен 2 в квадрате".

Как правильно поступать в таком случае? Переотвечать? Игнорировать?

Comment: Если ответ хороший и полезный, то задавайте рядом сами хороший вопрос для него и постите ответ туда. А автор первоначального вопроса - "сам себе злобный буратино".

Comment: Когда-то встречал мнение, что существенно переделывать вопрос после того, как на него уже дали ответ, нельзя, и теперь по-хорошему автор должен создать новый правильно сформулированный вопрос

Comment: `Получаю минус с комментарием` C чего вы взяли, что минус поставил автор вопроса? Разве голосовать против не есть привилегия, доступная с некоторого количества репутации?

Comment: Сделайте откат. Если автор вопроса будет упорствовать, то зовите модератора.